# select categories and count its subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, categories

I have two tables (category and subcategory). I want to show in a query all the categories that I have and show the count for each one.

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot,
Diogo.

Comment: Can you show your database structure and some sample data? Also is there a PHP side to this or is it just a mysql question?

Comment: can you post the query you are currently running?

Comment: Hint: use `left join`, `group by` and `count()`

Comment: Show us your attempt at this problem.

Comment: @mindaJalaj the query is that: SELECT count(sub_title) AS SubCatTitle, cat_title FROM category, subcategory WHERE cat_id = sub_cat_id GROUP BY cat_title

Comment: @MinistryofChaps the query is that: SELECT count(sub_title) AS SubCatTitle, cat_title FROM category, subcategory WHERE cat_id = sub_cat_id GROUP BY cat_title

Comment: sub_ is from table subcategory and cat_ is from table category!

Comment: Writing the desired query - SELECT count(s.sub_title) as SubCatTitle ,s.cat_title FROM `subcategory` s,category c where s.sub_cat_id = c.cat_id group by c.cat_title.   Hope it helps

Comment: @mindaJalaj what is the "c" before the WHERE?

Comment: is it working? we have added alias names to our table, for avoidng column name collisions  between tables.so category is represented as c

Comment: @mindaJalaj no, because "cat_title" it's a field from the category table and you put like "s.cat_title"...

Comment: it was a typo, did it work after changing from s to c?

Comment: @mindaJalaj I have already altered and did not give errors, but for example, if the category "footwear" has no subcategory, it does not appear when executing the query, as I do with the query I had before.

Comment: in this query it wont appear since, we are doing, - where s.sub_cat_id = c.cat_id, which means, cat_id should exist in both the tables, if you want it to appear, you can go ahead with left join query for the same

Comment: @mindaJalaj i never worked with the left join... :/ can you help me? :)

Comment: Okay, so here is the query - SELECT count(s.sub_title) as SubCatTitle ,c.cat_title FROM category c left join subcategory s, on s.sub_cat_id = c.cat_id group by c.cat_title

Comment: hey, did it work?

Comment: @mindaJalaj You just wrote an extra comma in the query, but apart from that, it was correct! thanks a lot! :D

Comment: hahahaha, grammatical errors are neglected in this platform. Anyways sorry for the trouble, hope the query helped you.

Comment: ahah thanks a lot! <3